# How to disable button opacity in Android Compose

Tags: android

I'm trying to have floating buttons over a TextField and after trying various settings the text from behind the text always transpires. Is there a special way to fix this?
[image]

Here's my code for the Composable:

```
@Composable
fun EditNoteScreen() {
    var textContent by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start, modifier =   Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Button(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small, onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
        {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Close, "")
        }
    }

    TextField(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), value = textContent, onValueChange = { textContent = it })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well you need the `TextField` to appear behind the `Button`. So you need a `Box()` and place first the `TextField` and then the `Button`.

For example something like:

```
@Composable
fun EditNoteScreen() {
    
    var textContent by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        TextField(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), value = textContent, onValueChange = { textContent = it })

        Button(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small, onClick = { /*TODO*/ })
        {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Close, "")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you, I'm still learning compose...

Answer (score 0):

After playing with this much more I realized that changing the order of Composables affects their layering, i.e.:

```
fun myScreen()
{
   Composable1()
   Composable2() //Comp2 is on top of Comp1
}
```

on the other hand

```
fun myScreen()
{
   Composable2()
   Composable1() //now Comp1 is on top of Comp2
}
```

so it doesn't matter if it's a Box layout or a Row, replacing the Composable order does the trick, hence the answer I accepted, even though works does not get at the heart of the issue.

Comment: Of course it matters :) If it wasn't a `Box()` and it was a `Column()` then the one it would appear `bellow` or `above` the other, or if it was a `Row()` then the one would appear `next` to the other. So you need to have a `Box()` as top Composable in order to make the one appear `bellow or in front of the other`, which was your requirement!

Comment: You can also have an empty `Surface()` which I suppose was your top Composable on your answer above but `Surface()` was not meant for re arranging composables, so I have not included it in my comment.